# Can I isolate an environment variable name in the expand() function

Tags: environment-variables

In my shell, I can use curly braces to isolate the names of environment variables.

For example, if I have two env vars, ONE and TWO, equal to 1 and 2, then

```
> echo "$ONE_$TWO"
ONE_: Undefined variable
> echo "${ONE}_${TWO}"
1_2
```

I like to try something similar with Vim's expand() function, but the curly braces don't help.

```
:echo expand('$ONE_$TWO')
$ONE_$TWO
:echo expand('${ONE}_${TWO}')
$ONE_$TWO
```

Comment: You _may_ not need `expand` if the variables are already known to vim (`:help expr-env-expand`): `:echo $ONE .. '_' .. $TWO`

Comment: Yes, this is true.   If I were to construct a string on my own using Vimscript, I would do it like this with the dot (or VIm9 double dot).  However, my plugin is being used my my colleagues who are not as experienced with Vimscript.  I included an option for a user to define a non-default path in their .vimrc.   If a user defines a string containing env vars, then I'd like give that string to the expand() function in my plugin.   My end-users would have an easier time putting curly braces around the env var (just like in a shell script) than to use Vimscript.

Comment: There is also a string interpolation syntax I’ve forgotten (maybe a $ prefix?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put any character that is invalid in an environment variable name after the environment variable name, it will force the expansion. Example:

```
ec expand('$SHELL-$HOME')
```

Output:

```
/bin/zsh-/home/wilson
```

Then you can replace all instances of the invalid character with an underscore:

```
ec expand('$SHELL-$HOME')->substitute('-', '_', 'g')
```

Output:

```
/bin/zsh_/home/wilson
```

I recommend you define your own function in your vimrc for this

```
function! Exp(str)
    return expand(a:str)->substitute('-', '_', 'g')
endf
```

Then run `ec Exp('$SHELL-$HOME')` as needed.

Or you could even do:

```
function! Exp(str)
    return expand(a:str->substitute('_', '-', 'g'))->substitute('-', '_', 'g')
endf
```

and run it as `ec Exp('$SHELL_$HOME')`. The only concern is if the *unexpanded* string contains hyphens or if the values of the environment variables contain hyphens.

Of course, it doesn't have to be a hyphen, it could be anything other than an alphanumeric or underscore. You might come up with some weird character that will definitely never cause undesired results. You could even use a single closing curly brace and use `expand('$SHELL}_$HOME')->substitute('}', '', 'g')`, as long as the result will definitely not contain any `}` characters.